# Can I get a graph of job workflows in Azure Devops similar to GitHub Actions?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-webjobs

I want to visualize the jobs running in a pipeline. You can refer to the image attached below.
[image: 1]

I am expecting to get a graphical representation of all jobs running in a pipeline. I want to see which jobs are running in parallel and which are running sequential in Azure Devops

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Hi @Vanit Agarwal, please check colin's answer. If it helps, please [mark it as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) according to How does accepting an answer work. Or please post new comments if you still have any queries. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's shown in [the pipeline runs page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runs?view=azure-devops), but the documentation doesn't seem to have an example screenshot of parallel stages, so here's one from my own multi stage parallel pipeline:

[image: multi stage parallel pipeline screenshot]

Note with [Azure DevOps naming of Stages, Jobs, and Steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66741757/12744), the level that most closely reflects what is shown in the image in your question is "Stages" not "Jobs".   "Jobs" is the next level down, which can be run in parallel, but can't be displayed as a graph AFAIK.  This is how you would structure your YAML to get what is shown in my image:

```
stages:
- stage: Download_Installer
  jobs:
   - job: Download
- stage: Create_Environment_aaa
  dependsOn: ['Download_Installer']
  jobs:
  - job: one
  - job: two
  - job: three
  - job: four
- stage: Create_Environment_bbb
  dependsOn: ['Download_Installer']
  jobs:
  - job: one
  - job: two
  - job: three
  - job: four
```